# picture is not being fetched

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio and making website in asp.net.

I have made a folder named "Images" from where I am calling picture through css using `background:url("images/loading.gif")` but picture is not showing when I run the application.

Please help me

Comment: Is your HTML running from the parent directory of `images`?

Comment: What do you mean I didn't understand.. sorry!

Comment: What is the file path of the image in comparison to the file that is being executed?

Comment: D:\MatrimonialSite\MatrimonialSite\SliderTry.aspx
this is the path of the aspx page and
D:\MatrimonialSite\MatrimonialSite\Images\closelabel.gif
this is the path of Image

Comment: Try using `background:url("Images/loading.gif")` and see if that works. Is the loading.gif file in that folder?

Comment: yes this file is there. And I have also tried what you have said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :-

```
background-image: url(../images/loading.gif);
```

If your directory is like:-

```
|
+--Css (folder)
|  \--Stylesheet.css
|
+--images (folder)
|  \--loading.gif
|
\--Default.aspx
```

Comment: hey I did background: url(../images/closelabel.gif); with 4 pictures because they all are in the same folder i.e "Images". But only 1 picture is showing not all the rest

Comment: @user3005601 if others are not showing please mae it sure are they in the images folder and if yes than what is the path that must be same as above

Comment: Yes others are existing in that same folder so path must be same for all

Comment: @user3005601 yes path must be same for all and it must work .